# ComboBox onAction method causes InvocationTargetException caused by ClassCastException

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, combobox, scenebuilder

Got the ComboBox and few other FX items.

```
<ComboBox fx:id="YearComboBox" editable="true" layoutX="565.0" layoutY="14.0" onAction="#handleYear" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Year" />
```

code:

```
        @FXML
        public void initialize(){
            YearComboBox.getItems().addAll(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)-1,Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)+1);
            //setting another buttons etc.
        }

        @FXML
        private void handleYear() {
            System.out.println(YearComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            year = (int) YearComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        }
```

Some of them already have onAction methods, for example ChoiceBox is working fine, but ComboBox is behaving strange, as it seems to call the onAction method twice: while choosing some value and while clicking on any other FX item like Button or the Choice Box. When I just print it to the console, it appears two times: when performing some action on combobox and second time when performing some action on another item and no exceptions are thrown, but when I'm trying to assign is's value to te variable I am getting the exception while, let's say "leaving" the ComboBox. Already searched and found some info about the bug related to ComboBox but I think this is about something else here, why is the exception caused by ClassCastException? And about what String casting is the log "talking"? 
Important: this error does not appear until you click on any other JavaFX Item (button, choice box etc).

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$70(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
    at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:105)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setValue(ComboBoxBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl.setTextFromTextFieldIntoComboBoxValue(ComboBoxPopupControl.java:405)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl.lambda$new$291(ComboBoxPopupControl.java:82)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.scene.Node$FocusedProperty.notifyListeners(Node.java:7718)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$13.invalidated(Scene.java:2077)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.setFocusOwner(Scene.java:3924)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.requestFocus(Scene.java:3971)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3910)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.requestFocus(Scene.java:2044)
    at javafx.scene.Node.requestFocus(Node.java:7879)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ChoiceBoxBehavior.mousePressed(ChoiceBoxBehavior.java:120)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$358(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at application.controllers.ControllerCalendar.handleYear(ControllerCalendar.java:34)
    ... 81 more
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 2):

`YearComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()` is returning a `String`.  Attempting to cast it to `int` (which the system reinterprets as a cast to `Integer` followed by unboxing) therefore fails.  You should instead use `Integer.parseInt(YearComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString())`, and even then you need to be prepared to handle the `NumberFormatException` that will arise if the user enters data that is not a valid string representation of an integer.

Comment: The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Anyway, the problem occurs only when "leaving" the ComboBox and clicking on another Button etc.

Comment: Add a `toString()` call (answer updated) or cast the result to a `String`, since that's what it actually is. The *timing* of the exception is not germane to its nature, which is clear from the posted stack trace.

Comment: The parameters to `addAll` are `int`s autoboxed to `Integer`. Since the selection model should use the items of the `items` list, a string conversion shouldn't be necessary. (Needless to mention that I cannot reproduce the issue with the code provided in the question...)

Comment: @fabian just add some random button, even without it's onAction method. When selecting some position from ComboBox everything is okay, but after selecting some position when you click on random button ComboBox seems to call it's onAction one more time  (why?) and above exception is being thrown then.

Comment: @Sheb when you specify `editable="true"`, updates may be triggered from the textfield, whose content is a string. You are responsible for specifying how to convert textual user input to an object of your domain. See [`ComboBox.setConverter(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#setConverter-javafx.util.StringConverter-)…

Comment: @Holger That's it!
YearComboBox.setConverter(new IntegerStringConverter());

Thanks! It's working now.